# justgage no element with id 0 angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, justgage

I wrote a directive to `JustGage` plugin as follows.

```
function justGage() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                value: '='
            },
            template: '<div id="{{id}}" class="200x160px" style="margin-top: 5vh"></div>',
            link: function ($scope, $element) {

                var g = new JustGage({
                    id: $scope.id,
                    value: $scope.value,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    minLabelMinFontSize: 15,
                    maxLabelMinFontSize: 15,
                    valueMinFontSize: 40,
                    valueFontColor: '#ededed'
                });
            }
        };
    }
```

In my controller I assign values to `id` and gauge `value`

```
$element.id = "gauge";
$element.value = $scope.data;
```

My html is as follows.

```
<just-gage></just-gage>
```

Then I get an error as `"justgage : no element with id 0"`. In my directive I added the same id to both template and JustGage object. 
How can I solve this issue to render the gauge?

Comment: pls paste the html, where you used the directive.

Comment: you should remove,  `scope: {
                id: '@',
                value: '='
            }` from the directive

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: remove the scope from the directive and check.

Comment: After I removed the scope. I got this error
* justgage: Make sure to pass the existing element id or parentNode to the constructor.

Comment: `console.log($scope)` once in your directive, and where did you set `id` and `value` in the controller

Comment: console.log($scope) says ChildScope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127369/discussion-between-sravan-and-shashika).

Answer (score 0):

You create a new child scope in your directive, so it doesn't know of the `id` and `value` you assigned in the controller.

You can do something like this:

```
link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

    var g = new JustGage({
        id: $attrs.id,
        value: $attrs.value,
        // ..
    });

}
```